# Debug external classes in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to debug external classes (MVC in this case), but I can´t get it to work.

I have turned of the "Enable Just My Code" option under the menu Debug - Options and turned on "Anable .NET Framework source stepping" and "Enable source server support" (please see the enclosed image).
[debug settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY9Tw.png)

I have also loaded all symbols from "Microsoft Symbol Servers" (please see image)
[Loaded all symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le5sx.png)

When I click a row in the Call Stack view I get "Source Not Available" (see image).
[Source Not Available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BmdQ.png)

When I look in the modules window (under Debug - Windows - Modules menu) it looks like the System.Web.Mvc.dll is loaded.

[Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rdES.png)

When I try to step in to external code with F11 nothing happens the debuger just continous to the next row in my code.

Any ideas why this dosen´t work?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Lira, please copy the .PDB of this external dll to the current compiling directory or rebuilding the external library using debug mode, then copy both .dll and the .pdb file to the bin folder. BTW, does this issue happens to all your solutions like this?

Comment: Hi Sara, Thanks for your reply. I copied the System.Web.Mvc.pdb to my bin folder and tried to click on a row that calls a method in System.Web.Mvc.dll in the Call Stack view, but I only get "Source Not Available". When I try to step in to the method System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View("viewName", "masterName", model) with F11 nothing happens. The debuger only steps on to the next row in my own file. I cann´t say if this happens to other solutions because I am new to C# and Visual Studio, so I only have this solution.